# How to check for/retrieve record-specific error message, e.g. by errors added through sObject.addError or validation rule?

Tags: apex, sobject, adderror

I'm wondering about the [documentation for the sObject class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) (API 50).

It clearly states this for `hasErrors()`:

> Returns true if an SObject instance has associated errors. The error
> message can be associated to the SObject instance by using
> SObject.addError(), validation rules, or by other means.

However this is not the actual behavior.

I've tested three scenarios:

1. Validation rule on Account with error location "top of page". Fire if Account.Description is blank
2. Validation rule on Account with error location "Name". Fire if Account.Name contains a "2"
3. Add error in Account trigger through Apex by calling: `Trigger.new[0].addError('PHONE!');` if Account.Phone is null

When I perform DML on an account that matches the scenarios, the "hasErrors" method does not behave as described. Here's my test case:

```
try
{
    insert acc;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.debug('Has Errors: ' + acc.hasErrors());
    System.debug('Msg: ' + ex.getMessage());
}
```

and I tested the above mentioned scenarios with this input and the corresponding result:

```
// hasErrors() = FALSE but DmlException message about missing description
Account acc1 = new Account(Name = 'Test', Phone = '123');

// hasErrors() = TRUE and error message about no "2" allowed in Account.Name
Account acc2 = new Account(Name = 'Test2', Phone = '123');

// hasErrors() = FALSE but DmlException message about missing phone
Account acc3 = new Account(Name = 'Test2');
```

As you can see only the second scenario where an error is tied to an *sobject's FIELD* results in `sObject.hasError()` to be `true`. When the error is only tied to the entire object and not to a field, it always returns `false`.
According to the documentation this should not be the case.
The same applies for `sObject.getErrors()` - for scenarios #1 and #3 it returns an empty array and is also documented otherwise.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug?

I know I could get extract the errors for #1 and #3 from the DML exception but this would be much more implementation effort and I'd rather use the system in place...